# How to query SQL Server (on premises) from Azure using a PowerShell runbook?

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2016, azure-runbook

I need to execute a query against an on-premise SQL Server 2016 instance from our Azure automation account for the purpose of sending emails based on the content in the database.

The client is unable to establish a session, it is a networking issue. I think I might be missing a middle step or have not given the SQL Server module enough information to target our on premises server.

1. I am using the `sqlserver` module
2. I have checked the TCP/IP settings are enabled for the on premises instance
3. I turned on SQL Server Browser (i do not think this is required)
4. I tested the code on my local Powershell ISE and it worked
5. I tried using Windows Auth and SQL Server auth

Code:

```
Import-Module sqlserver

$from       = "x.y@dom.com"
$to         = "email@gmail.com"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.sendgrid.net"
$SMTPPort   = "587"
$username   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
$password   = "xxxxxxxxxxx"

$subject    = "Email test from Azure SMTP server"
$body       = "Test email body, no content to see here!"

#$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort)
#$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password)
#$smtp.Send($From, $To, $subject, $body)



function Get-EmailBody{

}

<#
    Get all emails which have been merged into the emailChangeHistory table with the flag emailSent = 0.
#>
function Get-ChangeHistory($sqlServer, $database, $emailSent = 0){
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select 1" -ServerInstance "servername" 
}

Get-ChangeHistory -sqlServer $null, -database $null, -emailSent $null
```

I get this error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
>   The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL 
>   Server)
>
> At line:30 char:5
>   +     Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select 1" -ServerInstance "servername"
>   +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExceptionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Comment: Have you tested what "servername" resolves to from a runbook? Is there any network path between where the runbook execuates and the SQL Server?

Comment: @Persistent13 I executed Resolve-DNSName -name "servername" which returned servername.domain.local.